# Can't add items to QMap

Tags: c++, qt, qmap

I have a problem. I assume I'm doing something really dumb. I'm new to C++ and Qt.

I have a class SavedVar. I'm trying to add a key/value to a private member Qmap. When I call SavedVar::addVar(), the program crashes. SavedVar::addvar() is receiving 'id' and 'notes' correctly.

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QMap>
#include "variation.h"
#include <QTableWidget>
#include "mainwindow.h"

class SavedVar : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SavedVar(QObject *parent = 0);
    void addVar(QString id, QString notes);
    void saveVar(QString varText );
    void removeSavedVar(QList <QTableWidgetItem*>  &varList);
    QString generateSaveFile();
    void loadVarFile(QString filename);
    const QMap<QString, QString>*getVmapPtr();

private:
    QMap <QString, QString>  vmap; 

}; 

void SavedVar::addVar(QString id, QString notes)
{
    vmap[id]= notes;
}
```

I'm struggling to understand the debug output in Qt creator:

```
0   QBasicAtomicInt::operator!= qbasicatomic.h  75  0x4116e3    
1   QMap<QString, QString>::detach  qmap.h  202 0x41ede2    
2   QMap<QString, QString>::operator[]  qmap.h  526 0x41d241    
3   SavedVar::addVar    savedvar.cpp    17  0x44afc9    
4   SavedVar::loadVarFile   savedvar.cpp    82  0x44b4b8    
5   MainWindow::load_data   mainwindow.cpp  190 0x40d5fe
```

Cheers,

Neil

Comment: You should be passing *heavy* objects such as `QString` by reference or pointer instead of by value. Apart from that, I cannot see anything in that code that gives a hint of your problem. The problem seems to be in another part of the code. Check, for example, each of the strings entering `addVar`, just in case they are ill-formed, empty, etc.

Comment: @Diego Devilla: I agree, there doesn't seem to be anything obvious wrong with the code posted. As for storing QStrings by reference or pointer, there is no need. QString uses implicit sharing (copy-on-write).

Comment: Can we see `SavedVar::loadVarFile` up to the `addVar` call and `MainWindow::load_data` up to the `loadVarFile` call?  It's likely that you're calling `addVar` with a bad `this` pointer, and the code makes it a few more function calls before crashing.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you didn't initialize the QMap object by doing so :

```
vmap = new(QMap <QString, QString>);
```

Then you can manipulate your object with insert() and remove().

Answer (score -1):

Have you tryed with the QMap method *insert* ?

```
void SavedVar::addVar(QString id, QString notes)
{
    vmap.insert(id, notes);
}
```